# Kali Linux VM: Permission denied to run shell script, as root

Tags: linux, virtualbox, permissions

I've just installed Kali Linux (Debian) in a VirtualBox VM. I want to install the VBOX Additions that will allow me to configure things like screen resolution (hopefully).

My problem is running the install script. I'm root, I've chmoded everything, I have the rights to execute the script but I still get 'Permission Denied'. I've tried with sudo as well.

Check the screen below:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you give the it 7XX permissions?

Comment: https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It might be that the `/media/cdrom0` filesystem has the `noexec` flag set. You can check this with:

```
mount -v | grep cdrom0
```

If there is `noexec` between the parentheses, files on the filesystem are not executable. (like `(noexec,nosuid,nodev)`)

You can try remounting the filesystem with the `exec` flag:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec,ro /media/cdrom0
```

note ro to indicate readonly.

Alternatively you can copy all files to disk and run the scripts from there.

Comment: Running `bash < ./autorun.sh` should also work.

Comment: Indeed, never thought about that. As a variation, `sh autorun.sh` is more commonly used.

Comment: Moreover, one needs `build-essential`, `module-assistant` and kernel's headers. [Here](http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-debian/) there is a nice summary of things to do for getting `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` to play nicely.

Comment: copying the files is the fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

No need to mess with remounts or anything. Just run:

`sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Answer (score 0):

The file you want to run is `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` , the files named `runasroot.sh` and `autorun.sh` will return that error even if you do change the attributes.

After you copy the contents of the Guest additions ISO to a folder on the guest machine if it appears in green text when listed in a terminal then it is already executable. If not you can type into a terminal after navigating to the directory where you saved the files on the guest machine.
`chmod -x VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
 or just right click on it and select properties and then select the permissions tab and click the execute checkbox - allow executing as a program.

Answer (score -2):

*The problem is due to the permission not set to executable to fix this*

**FIX 1**

COPY THE EXECUTABLE TO THE HOME DIRECTORY AND THEN RUN THESE COMMANDS

```
chmod -x filename.sh

./filename.sh
```

it should work..

**Fix 2**

```
Change the permission of the file system in which the *.sh file is located.
```